# yii use message in module

Tags: php, yii, module, components, bootstrapping

I want to use message for one of my module and i have two type of language. one is en and the other is dk so i want them to be used with my module and i have placed the message folder in my module so folder structure is something like :

```
application >  modules > modulename > message > en > app.php and de > app.php
```

so i want to use this language in my module i. can you suggest me what changes or configuration i need to do in my module config file so that this should work?

this is my module file

```
public function init()
{
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', Yii::getPathOfAlias('smsLog.extensions.bootstrap'));
Yii::app()->setComponent('bootstrap', array('class'=>'smsLog.extensions.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap'));

Yii::app()->language='en_us';
$this->setImport(
    array(
        'smsLog.models.*',
        'smsLog.components.*',
        'smsLog.components.Services.*',
        'smsLog.components.Services.Twilio.*',
        'smsLog.components.Services.Twilio.Rest.*',
        'smsLog.message.*',
    )
);
$this->configure(array(
    'preload'=>array('bootstrap'),
    'components'=>array(
        'bootstrap' => array(
            'class'=>'smsLog.extensions.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
        ),
    ),

));

$this->preloadComponents();
```

}

Please check the image below :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all in your **moduleName.php** file **you need to import the message folder** like this

```
class ModuleName extends CWebModule
{
public function init()
    {
$this->setImport(array(
            'smsLog.messages.*',
        ));
}
}
```

Now create a folder in your **smsLog  with name messages and then create a folder en_us**. SO the structure would be something like
**smsLog/messages/en_us/app.php**
In your app.php write this

```
<?php 
return array(
'your message'=>' I am translated',
);
```

Then in your controllers inside your module you can use the languange you want to like

```
Yii::t('smsLogModule.app','your message');
```

**Hope this helps** :)

### Update

You need to use  `Yii::t('smsLogModule.app','your message');`
i.e You need to prepend first argument of your **Yii::t** with **the name of your module with the word Module.**

Comment: what is your source and the target language?

Comment: i am using this but still no repnse Yii::app()->language='en'; 
    echo Yii::t('app', 'CONST_LBL_TEXT_LOGIN');

Comment: change en to en_us and change your folder name in messages too

Comment: no even that is not working i have added the image please take a look of it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44680/discussion-between-let-me-see-and-anil-dhiman)